# How to know the Memory Usage of specific functionlity?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, process, out-of-memory

I wanted to know the how much memory is utilized by specific functionality of application.
I am running the Java based web application in Chrome browser (or any browser), It consist the form approve functionality like this,

Step

1. Select the record/records.
2. select the status as approved.
3. click on submit button form gets successfully approved.

This works fine for number of records are less than 50, but for 500 form is shown as memory issue.

Now my question is, how to find the memory usage of submit functionality. so that can i show the exact understandable figures.

Comment: You want to know the memory used by the application on the client side or the server side? I think that wasnt clear in your question.

Comment: What container? Jboss, tomcat, Websphere, Weblogic?

Comment: there are some good videos on performance tuning by oracle on youtube like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6qx_zvpOyI&

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Java profiler(jvisualvm). It exist in the bin directory of Java installation folder.

You can start your application, same time start monitoring main tread through this profiling tool. Then take Heap snapshot when ever you want, this will not just tell you about memory usage by individual classes, it even help you identify memory leaks too.

Comment: thanks for answer, Java profiler & process Explorer helps me.